# Changing length of an arrows from a vertex to itself

Tags: lyx, arrows, xy-pic, lengths

I'm working with **LyX**.

I would like to change the length of an arrow from a vertex to itself. I would like to make the arrow stretch longer up before returning down to the encircled vertex. The code I have been using so far, inside the `\xymatrix` in the LyX Math-box, is:

```
*+[o][F-]{e}\ar@(ul,ur)
```

How should this code be modified in LyX in order to lengthen the arrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As canaaerus says the control points option is the way to go.  To reproduce the `ul` direction use a point of the form `(-x,x)` and for the `ur` direction `(x,x)`.  The standard size is produced with `x` roughly `10`. Now with the correct syntax you can write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}

\begin{document}
\( \begin{xy}\xymatrix{ e\ar @`{(-10,10),(10,10)}  }\end{xy} \qquad
    \begin{xy}\xymatrix{ e\ar @`{(-20,20),(20,20)}  }\end{xy} \)

\end{document}
```

and get

[image: Selfarrow sample]

To make this narrower, reduce the size of the x-coordinates of the control points

```
\( \begin{xy}\xymatrix{ e\ar @`{(-10,20),(10,20)} } \end{xy} \)
```

[image: Narrow selfarrow]

See the [manual of `xypic`](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyrefer.pdf), particularly the section on curves, for more information about control points.

Note that if you wish to place such arrows at a different node of your `\xymatrix` then you should be careful about absolute vs. relative coordinates, one way to deal with this is to package the node into an `\xybox`.  Here is an example, including the node formatting in your original question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\( \begin{xy}\xymatrix{ \xybox{ *=+[o][F]{e}\ar @`{(-10,10),(10,10)} } &
   \xybox{ *=+[o][F]{e}\ar @`{(-20,20),(20,20)} } }\end{xy} \) 

\end{document}
```

[image: Matrix example]

and here is a further example demonstrating that `xypic` treats these nodes correctly in that arrows point to the circled node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{xy}
    \xymatrix{
    \xybox{ *=+<12pt>[o][F]{e}\ar @`{(-10,10),(10,10)} }
    \ar[r]^\pi
    \ar@{.>}[rd]_q &
    \xybox{ *=+<12pt>[o][F]{g}\ar @`{(-20,20),(20,20)} } \ar[d]^p \\
    & \xybox{ *=+<12pt>[o][F]{f}\ar @`{(-10,-20),(10,-20)}|a }
    }
  \end{xy}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sectond matrix example]

Notice that I have used `+<12pt>` to get larger circles around the nodes.

Comment: Andrew, thanks a lot for your answer! It's very helpful!   :)

Comment: This is fantastic, and it can be made even better. :) To use relative coordinates, you can just write "\ar@`{p+(-10,10),p+(10,10)}", because "p" is parsed as the coordinates of the source of the arrow (see paragraph 24q of the XY-pic reference manual).

Comment: @Vectornaut That is a very useful way of specifying these relative coordinates without packing up in a box.

Comment: I'm glad you like it!

Answer (score 1):

First of all `e\ar@(ul,ur)` seems to have the same effect for me as your example. To make it into a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{xy}\xymatrix{ e\ar@(ul,ur) }\end{xy} \]

\end{document}
```

Now I think the problem can be solved by putting explicit curve control points. Compare `24q` in the [XY-pic Reference Manual](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyrefer.pdf). Then the syntax should look like `e\ar@'{a,b}` where `a` and `b` are control points which are to the upper left and upper right, but sufficiently far away.

Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with this function yet.